# How to do something in Rx subscription only after valid value?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription

How to do something in Rx subscription only after valid value?

For example, I receive 'null', 'null' and only after this array with data

For example:

```
this.someStream$.subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  if (data) {
    this.someVar= data.map(item => new SomeModel(item ));
});
```

How to avoid "`if (data) {}`"

Comment: `this.someStream$.pipe(filter(data => data !== null)).subscribe((data: any[]) => this.someVar= data.map(item => new SomeModel(item )))`

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested, the `filter` pipe does the job, but you explicitely don't want to have a conditional, which can be understood from a verbosity perspective. This is not very pretty, right?

```
filter(data => data !== undefined)
filter(data => !!data)
```

There are two solutions to avoid the `!==` or the shorthand `!!data`.

First, you can make use of the `Boolean` constructor. It is a function with signature `(any) => boolean`, that's why you can do this:

```
filter(Boolean)
```

Be careful though, als falsy values (false, "", 0) will also be filtered that way. It's only save to use with `object`.

Even better and more reusable is creating an own operator, that would look like this:

```
function filterEmpty<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
    return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(filter(val => val != undefined));
}
```

Then, you can use it with your code example:

```
this.someStream$
    .pipe(filterEmpty())
    .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.someVar = data.map(item => new SomeModel(item ));
    });
```

**TYPES**

There is another concern with this approach, and that is types.

Imagine this:

```
class X {
    public a;
}

let x: X | undefined = undefined;

of(x)
    .pipe(filter(y => !!y))
    .subscribe(y => {
        let i = y.a;
});
```

We will get a type error when assigning `i`, as `y` is `X | undefined`. Very unfortunate.

But with this typed operator, we can convert `X | undefined` into `X`:

```
export function filterNullable<T>(): OperatorFunction<T | undefined, T> {
    return (source: Observable<T | undefined>) => source.pipe(
        filter<T | undefined, T>(
            function (val: T | undefined): val is T {
                return val !== undefined;
            }));
}
```

Very handy.

Comment: A nicer way of handling the condition and promoting re-usability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` for this purpose:

```
this.someStream$
  .filter(data => data !== null || typeof data != "undefined")
  .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.someVar = data.map(item => new SomeModel(item));
  });
```